# Creation flow: I have a Wizard that creates campaign, but it has multiple sub wizards and steps

Tags: workflow, wizard, task-flow

I have a problem don't know how to effectively solve it. My sketch below illustrates briefly the flow.

Problem
I have a wizard that creates (objects) so it has 5 steps with sub steps. Once all steps are completed an(object) is created.That was original design. But now sub steps have been added they are sub wizards. If user don't find what they want then they can create things in sub wizards and add those to main wizard in middle of workflow.

Above has lot of issues
1. It makes workflows too lengthy
2. UI has 3 levels of breadcrumbs 
3. Overall UX is not so good.

Can you point me to examples where above issues are solved in a much more elegant way?

One Example I can think of is
1. Turbo Tax tax preparation flow its multistep and long and nice experience has some intelligence built in

Looking forward for suggestions/ examples

Best

[[image: Campaign Creation Flow[1]]

Comment: IMHO you're losing sight of what a wizard is and how (and why) to use it. This is a very broad question, but with the info you provide I don't think a wizard is appropriate

Answer (score 1):

would be easier if more context was added to the question. but here's my 2 cents.

Instead of visualising it as a wizard with sub wizards, you could look at it as a wizard with checklists or options within it. Also you could look into natural language form or that kind of thinking to simplify things overall.